# Why does pandas roll a week forward when using resample with W-MON frequency?

Tags: python, pandas

As example, I have the following code which creates a dataframe with an index containing a single value - the date '2018-03-06' (a Tuesday).  Note that this date falls in the week of 2018-03-05 (a Monday):

```
values = [1, 1, 1]
dates = pd.to_datetime(np.repeat('2018-03-06', 3))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': values
}, index=dates)
df.resample('W-MON').size()
```

which produces:

```
2018-03-12    3
Freq: W-MON, dtype: int64
```

Why does pandas roll the date forward one week?  I would have expected the result to have been resampled to 2018-03-05 since that is the week during which the values were generated and I'm using `freq='W-MON'`.

**UPDATE**

As was pointed out, I needed to add the `label` argument to `resample` which defines which bin edge to use.  Using `label='left'` solves the problem of bucketing the dates in the correct week except when the date falls on the start of the week (in this case, Monday).  For example, if I apply resample to the date 2018-03-05 using `label='left'` then the resampled value is 2018-02-26 when it should be 2018-03-05.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try using `label` and `closed` [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample):

```
values = [1, 1, 1]
dates = pd.to_datetime(np.repeat('2018-03-06', 3))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': values
}, index=dates)
df.resample('W-MON', label='left',closed='left').size()
```

Output:

```
2018-03-05    3
Freq: W-MON, dtype: int64
```

And,

```
values = [1, 1, 1]
dates = pd.to_datetime(np.repeat('2018-03-05', 3))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': values
}, index=dates)
df.resample('W-MON', label='left',closed='left').size()
```

Output:

```
2018-03-05    3
Freq: W-MON, dtype: int64
```

> **Interesting note** about the docs, the signature states that 'closed'
>   defaults to None.  However, the docstring states that 'closed' default
>   'left'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's done this way and I agree that the behaviour you expected seems more intuitive. You can get your desired result by passing `label='left'` as a keyword parameter. The default value in this case was  `'right'`.

```
df.resample('W-MON', label='left').size()
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

> **label** : *{‘right’, ‘left’}*
>
> Which bin edge label to label bucket with. The default is ‘left’ for
>   all frequency offsets except for ‘M’, ‘A’, ‘Q’, ‘BM’, ‘BA’, ‘BQ’, and
>   ‘W’ which all have a default of ‘right’.

I guess `'W-MON'` still counts as `'W'` which is why the default is `'right'` and therefore your example gave a result of `'2018-03-12'` rather than `'2018-03-05'`.

Comment: My bad, guess I should have RFTM more closely.  Thanks!

Comment: This still doesn't work as expected if the date values on the start of a new week i.e. Monday.  For example, if I apply `resample` to '2017-03-06' (a Monday), the resampled value is '2017-02-27' which is one week prior.  The result should be the beginning of the week in which '2017-03-06' falls which is '2017-03-06'.