# Group by Week in Pandas from SQL

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I currently have a data frame dfB which looks like follows

[image]

My goal is to now plot the number of orders per week. I am not sure of how to go about grouping my column most_recent_order_date per week,though. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [group by week in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281297/group-by-week-in-pandas)

Comment: @roganjosh I did not think It was a duplicate since they are doing something slightly different, and I don't know how to apply their answer to my problem.

Comment: Because I do not have a column like 'Name' that I want to group by. When I try just putting most_recent_order_date as my group by, it doesn't work: dfB.groupby('most_recent_order_date').resample('W-Mon', on='most_recent_order_date').sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='most_recent_order_date')

Comment: So you don't need to do a `grouby`, just a resample

Comment: Please consider dropping the images and replacing with a [good, reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Then we can get straight to solving the problem rather than building examples from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date column to `datetime` dtype if you haven't already.

```
dfB['most_recent_order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfB.most_recent_order_date)
```

Then use `resample`

```
dfB.resample('W-Mon', on='most_recent_order_date').sum()
```