# pandas long to wide from datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with a date index and 2 columns:

```
            val     week
2015-01-02  16729   1
2015-01-09  16225   2
2015-01-16  15250   3
2015-01-23  15690   4
2015-01-30  16025   5
...         ...     ...
2020-03-20  16417   12
2020-03-27  15481   13
2020-04-03  14216   14
2020-04-10  13113   15
2020-04-17  12825   16
```

What I would like to do is pivot or groupby the years, and then have month and week as the index.

```
            2015    ...    2020
01-1        16729   ...    ...
01-2        16225   ...    ...
01-3        15250   ...    ...
01-4        15690   ...    ...
01-5        16025   ...    ...
...         ...     ...    ...
03-12       ...     ...    16417
03-13       ...     ...    15481
04-14       ...     ...    14216
04-15       ...     ...    13113
04-16       ...     ...    12825
```

It would be preferable to instead just retain the month and day as the index, but as it is a weekly frequency the actual dates of the week differ across the years. It's not so much important that the dates be exact if there is a way to roll them up.

```
            2015    ...    2020
01-02       16729   ...    ...
01-09       16225   ...    ...
01-16       15250   ...    ...
01-23       15690   ...    ...
01-30       16025   ...    ...
...         ...     ...    ...
03-20       ...     ...    16417
03-27       ...     ...    15481
04-03       ...     ...    14216
04-10       ...     ...    13113
04-17       ...     ...    12825
```

I have tried using `pd.Grouper` and variations of `groupby` but I do not seem to be able to get it right. I am also open to other suggestions as to how to arrange this as the idea is for each year to be plotted as a separate line on the same line graph.

Comment: Did you try `pivot_table`? Something like `pd.pivot_table(df, values='val', index=df.index.strftime('%m-%W'), columns=df.index.year)` should go in the direction of your expected output I think.

Comment: @MrFuppes that actually worked, brilliant. I don't suppose you can think of a way to match to the nearest date instead of rolling up by week number? That would be preferable as I have interspersed NaNs in the returned frames.

Comment: What do you mean matching to the nearest date? Your dates seems to be all in Friday, do you mean they need to all be Fridays? If so, I'm guessing Mondays to Thursdays of the same week you want to match to Friday, but what about Sat/Sun? Regardless, it's possible to create a temp column with the adjusted dates and use that for the index instead.  Of course, you'll need to identify the `aggfunc` for the `pivot_table` to handle the duplicates.

Comment: @r.ook sorry, I should be more specific. when i do it with this method, some weeks are duplicated but with different months (ie 6-26, 7-26) and then there are NaN values in cells in the duplicate week where there are values in the other duplicate week, and vice versa. So 6-26 might have values for 2015,2016,2018, but 7-26 has values for 2017 and 2019. If that makes sense. Not sure how best to deal with this

Comment: of course a calendar week can fall between two months; so what you might want to do is [groupby week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45281439/10197418) after the pivot.

Comment: @MrFuppes would it be necessary to fill the NaN's first with 0's? And then groupby sum?

Comment: I think `sum()` will work fine with `NaN`s - if summing the values for every week is what you want in the first place.

Comment: @MrFuppes i tried to groupby using data[key] = data[key].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).sum() after converting back to a datetime index but it returns Cannot use '%W' or '%U' without day and year

Comment: When the values are duplicated for the given month-week index, you'll need to decide what to do with the `aggfunc`.  Did you want to sum them up? Average? the modification would be to add a `aggfunc=sum` param or whichever function you wish to apply into @MrFuppes's solution.

Answer (score 1):

after all the comments, seems like it's time for some code. A bit hacky but maybe this will help you:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# example df with some random values.
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['2015-01-02','2015-01-03','2015-01-16','2015-01-23','2015-01-30', '2020-01-01'],
                   'val': [16729, 16225, 15250, 15690, 16025, 999],
                   'week': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]})
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])

# pivot to get years as columns
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='val', columns=df['t'].dt.year, index=df['t'])

# create a new column "date" for later on... cast to datetime object for now
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.index.date)

# sum the values for every week and drop the original "t" (datetime) column
df2 = df1.groupby(df1.index.week).resample('W-Mon', on='date').sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='date').drop(columns=['t'])

# drop all rows that only hold zeros
df2 = df2.loc[~np.isclose(df2.loc[:, df2.columns != 'date'], 0)]

# finally, format the datetime column to string as desired
df2['month-week'] = df2['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%W')
```