# Pandas group by unique ID and Distinct date per unique ID

Tags: python, pandas

Title may be confusing: I have a dataframe that displays user_id sign in's during the week. My goal is to display the de-duped ID along with the de-duped dates per employee, in order to get a count of # days the user uniquely signed in for the week. So I've been trying to enforce a rule to make sure I'm only getting the distinct sign ins per day, per employee.

```
print(tempdf)
ID      date       
10301  1/4/2021   
10301  1/4/2021   
10301  1/5/2021    
10301  1/6/2021   
10301  1/7/2021    
10301  1/8/2021    
10302  1/4/2021    
10302  1/5/2021    
10302  1/6/2021    
10302  1/7/2021    
10302  1/8/2021
```

The only thing I can think of is trying to pass some form of .nunique(), but this instance would apply that count to my entire dataframe, as well as filter out all of my ID's before I can de-dupe them.

```
tempdf1=tempdf.groupby(['date'], as_index = False).nunique()
tempdf1['# days signed in for week'] = tempdf1.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count')
df=tempdf1.drop_duplicates(['ID']).copy()
```

This is the result I'm going for:

```
print(df)
ID      date    # days signed in for week     
10301  1/4/2021    5
10302  1/4/2021    5
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your sample data. You "have days signed in for week" in your input. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, that is incorrect. It was an attempt to show how the count for the first Id is wrong, but it's already demonstrated in my expected result. I'll get rid of that for people who check back on this page in the future!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281297/group-by-week-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- calculate start of week
- then it's a simple use of `count()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ID      date    # days signed in for week     
10301  1/4/2021    6
10301  1/4/2021    6
10301  1/5/2021    6
10301  1/6/2021    6
10301  1/7/2021    6
10301  1/8/2021    6
10302  1/4/2021    5
10302  1/5/2021    5
10302  1/6/2021    5
10302  1/7/2021    5
10302  1/8/2021    5"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df["weekStart"] = df['date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['date'].dt.dayofweek, unit='d')
df.groupby(["ID","weekStart"])["date"].count().reset_index()\
.rename(columns={"weekStart":"date","date":"# days signed in for week"})
```

Comment: it looks like this partially worked, but I had to use .nunique() instead of count in order to get distinct sign ins/day/employee. It also looks like the other columns I had in this dataframe have disappeared because they are of class type object from the grouping. Do I really have to convert them all back to strings in order to show the rest of the columns in the df? It seems that reset index and as_index=True doesn't work.