# How can I create a week column in a datetime format without the hours/minutes/seconds?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I was following this tutorial in order to create a week column in pandas: [group by week in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281297/group-by-week-in-pandas). The answers work fine if you have a date without hours, minutes and seconds. But it didn't work for me. I actually don't even need the summarizing part of the answer, just the week column creation, which seemed simple, but I couldn't find a solution.

I have a dataset with the id of the product, its price and the time it was sold, just like this:

```
sold_date            id         price
2020-01-01 20:00:01  A1         100
2020-01-02 10:03:01  B1         110
2020-01-02 11:10:01  B1         130
2020-02-03 22:20:01  A1         110
2020-02-04 23:05:01  A1         140
2020-02-04 21:00:05  B1         190
.
.
.
```

I just want to add a datetime column with the week of creation. I'm trying to get to this:

```
week_sold            id         price
2019-12-30           A1         100
2019-12-30           B1         110
2019-12-30           B1         130
2020-02-02           A1         110
2020-02-02           A1         140
2020-02-02           B1         190
.
.
.
```

I could also work with something like 2019-12-30 00:00:000. The problem with the solution of the link I was following is that it doesn't consider the hours, so when you create a week column just by subtracting 7 days you get different value for each row. You would get for the first two rows **2019-12-30 20:00:01** and **2019-12-30 10:03:01**.

Thanks in advance. Sorry about the data, I couldn't share the tables I'm working on.

Comment: Feb 3 2020 is the Monday, not Feb 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_period` and then grab the `start_time` of the period.

```
df['week_sold'] = df['sold_date'].dt.to_period('W').dt.start_time

            sold_date  id  price  week_sold
0 2020-01-01 20:00:01  A1    100 2019-12-30
1 2020-01-02 10:03:01  B1    110 2019-12-30
2 2020-01-02 11:10:01  B1    130 2019-12-30
3 2020-02-03 22:20:01  A1    110 2020-02-03
4 2020-02-04 23:05:01  A1    140 2020-02-03
5 2020-02-04 21:00:05  B1    190 2020-02-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the date type of your `sold_date` column, it might be as simple as converting to `pd.datetime` like this:

`df["sold_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["sold_date"])`

Once it's like this, you can access the date by doing:

`df["sold_date"] = df["sold_date"].dt.date`