# Groupby past date values into a list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like:

**EDIT**: I changed the dataframe to include a more general case of duplicate `Date`s.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2], 'Date':['2021-06-13','2021-06-13','2021-06-12','2021-06-12','2021-06-11','2021-06-11','2021-06-10'],'val':[4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')

    user    Date    val
0   1   2021-06-13  4
1   1   2021-06-13  5
2   1   2021-06-12  6
3   1   2021-06-12  7
4   1   2021-06-11  8
5   2   2021-06-11  9
6   2   2021-06-10  10
```

I would need to:

1. Groupby `user` and within each user:
2. Groupby `Date` within a timeframe (say 1 month) of each row (**EXCLUDING** that row's `Date`, we want to look at past month)
3. bundle the `val` into a list.

The desired output would look like:

```
    user    Date    val past
0   1   2021-06-13  4   [6, 7, 8]
1   1   2021-06-13  5   [6, 7, 8]
2   1   2021-06-12  6   [8]
3   1   2021-06-12  7   [8]
4   1   2021-06-11  8   []
5   2   2021-06-11  9   [10]
6   2   2021-06-10  10  []
```

For example, `user=1` has `val`s `[6,7,8]` in the past month from its `Date=2021-06-13` and so on.

**EDIT**: please note that there could be duplicate dates (like in example above for `Date=2021-06-13`), in which case, we still want to bundle `val`s for ONLY PAST `Date`s that does not include the current row's `Date`. For example, 1st and 2nd row both have same past up to `Date=2021-06-12` and EXCLUDING `Date=2021-06-13`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45281439/4975981) solves it if the current `Date` was included, but I need to **EXCLUDE** the row's current date. Of course, one naive solution would be to remove that row's values from the list after groupby but I am looking for something faster since data frame is huge.

Answer (score 1):

Curly one.

Steps and computation below

Convert val to str

```
df['val']=df['val'].astype(str)
```

Introduce index for reverse sorting and cum sum use

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

drop first and sort descending

```
df1=df[df.duplicated(subset='user', keep='first')].sort_values(by='index', ascending=False)
```

Cumsum vals in df1 and merge to df

```
 df3=df.merge(df1.val.map(lambda x : [x]).groupby(df.user).apply(lambda x : x.cumsum()).reset_index().rename(columns={'val':'past'}), on='index', how='left').fillna('NA')
df3['past']=np.where(df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x:x['Date'].duplicated(keep='last')), df3['past'].shift(-2),df3['past'].shift(-1))#df3['past'].shift(-1)
```

Outcome

```
     level_0  index  user   Date     val    past
0        0      0     1  2021-06-13   4  [8, 7, 6]
1        1      1     1  2021-06-13   5  [8, 7, 6]
2        2      2     1  2021-06-12   6        [8]
3        3      3     1  2021-06-12   7        [8]
4        4      4     1  2021-06-11   8         NA
5        5      5     2  2021-06-11   9       [10]
6        6      6     2  2021-06-10  10        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the definition of `df2` is missing in the solution. On another note, I think this solution fails in case of duplicate dates (I edited the example in question to include such case). Thank you and upvote.

Comment: Thank you. works now. However, it still suffers the duplicate date case. Can you think of a work around for it? I can manage a nasty work around, but wondering if there are cleaner/faster versions. Thank you.

Comment: Useful if you highlight the duplicate issue challenge

Comment: added an edit to highlight the challenge. Thank you

Comment: Lets try use np.where and see. See my last modification.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Seems like from what I understand, it only deals with one duplicate shift. However, there are arbitrary duplicates of each date. The ideal solution should be able to do it for any number of duplicate cases. I appreciate your effort in helping though.